# NHibernate "View or function 'x' is not updatable..." Error

Tags: nhibernate

Using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000, I'm getting the following error for a view I've not modified the data in when saving another table when running `Session.Flush()`:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: View or function 'x' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that NHibernate's model for the view had properties as non-nullable ints that were actually nullable in the view. NHibernate was automatically converting the null values to 0s, but then at Session.Flush() was trying to update the nulls in the database to be 0s.